# Can anyone explain the code about cin.tie() in C++?

Tags: c++, cin, tie

```
// redefine tied object
#include <iostream>     // std::ostream, std::cout, std::cin
#include <fstream>      // std::ofstream

int main () {
  std::ostream *prevstr;
  std::ofstream ofs;
  ofs.open ("test.txt");

  std::cout << "tie example:\n";

  *std::cin.tie() << "This is inserted into cout";
  prevstr = std::cin.tie (&ofs);
  *std::cin.tie() << "This is inserted into the file";
  std::cin.tie (prevstr);

  ofs.close();

  return 0;
}
```

We can get same output if we remove the line:

```
std::cin.tie (prevstr);
```

Why is this?

Comment: This statement modifies `std::cin`'s state but there are no more IO actions with `std::cin` after it so it has no observable effects/.

Comment: `*std::cin.tie() << "This is inserted into the file2";` if I add this line before ofs.close(); it still prints on console window, not in file. Why is this?

Comment: @shibly because `std::cin.tie (prevstr)` restores the previously tied ostream, which was `std::cout`

Answer (score 1):

`std::cin.tie(prevstr)` doesn't do anything in your original code because you didn't perform any operations on the stream afterward. `*std::cin.tie() << "This is inserted into the file2"` prints to `stdout` because `std::cin.tie(prevstr)` ties `std::cin` back to `std::cout`. `prevstr` points to the stream that `std::cin` was tied to before you set it to `ofs`, which is `std::cout`. If that line wasn't there it would have printed to the file.